# Syncfusion WPF GridDataControl formula verification

Tags: syncfusion

I have a Syncfusion WPF GridDataControl 9.4 version. Containing 2 columns 'A' and 'B'

In it's visible columns collection i have added a new column 'AddAB' and provided a formula for it as 'A+B' it works fine. A new column 'AddAB' is get added into the Grid with addition of each value in column A and B

Is there any way i can verify this formula 'A+B' which i provided for 'AddAB' column

Verification needs to be done for mathematical expression
and also if the column exists etc.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently we don’t have option to validate the expression externally. However we internally logged feature report for this and this feature will available in our next release.

Regards,
Sivakumar

Syncfusion